# how can i customize default values of twitter bootstrap CSS? e.g class=container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

in my `<head>` tags, ive placed the location of `bootstrap.css`

if i place `<div class="container">` it creates a fixed width.
what i wanted to happen is manipulate the default values of the `container` width by importing another set of stylesheet.

another scenario is, if i placed a `span8` how do i put background colors on it without actually editing the `bootstrap.css` rather, customize it using a new stylesheet.

does putting 2 stylesheet possible? then inherit / manipulate all values in the `bootstrap.css` in a new stylesheet?

i apologize if my explanation aren't that clear. its kinda hard to express verbally what i wanted to happen. :)

Comment: Read on [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), [Cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html) and [Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

Answer (score 0):

When you add a second stylesheet, you can override rules of the first one. Just make sure you add them to your html page in the right order.

If you want to make sure a rule won't be overridden you can add **!important** to it. Example:

```
.example {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: You should rarely use `!important` or `! important`. The rules of specificity can be used to calculate the specificity of the original selector, so that the succeeding (overriding) selector "outweighs" that selector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. That is what the "Cascading" part of CSS is. Short answer is to add your own style sheet after the bootstrap.css and before the responsive.css and your styles will be used because they are the latest definition, i.e. the rules "cascade" down.

Long answer is [take a look at the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html). There's a lot to learn there if you have the time.

Also have a look at the [bootstrap customization page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html)

Comment: `<link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
`<link href="./css/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">`
ive tried adding this inside `<head>`
created a `class="container"` and then created custom values in my `myStyle.css`. the `container` still uses the default config of it.

Comment: Your path appears to be wrong to your style sheet if your style sheet is one directory "up" that line should read `href="../css/myStyle.css" ` notice the extra period. I would recommend using absolute path names in general.  You should be able to views the source code and click on the link to your style sheet. Does it actually link there?