# CSS reset for font with HTML absolute font size

Tags: css

The scenario is the below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
....
<font size="5">Some large font text</font>
<font size="3">Some smaller font text</font>
....
```

How to you reset the font tag (ie, remove bootstrap's CSS)?

Comment: First, remove the deprecated `font` tags and replace them `span` tags...

Comment: To further clarify, I can't change the font code.. it's the clients HTML

Comment: See my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612751/how-can-i-customize-default-values-of-twitter-bootstrap-css-e-g-class-container

Comment: Thanks.. that won't work. The font copy is coming from a CMS managed by the client. The bootstrap link tag I control.

Comment: I honestly do not understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is this what you're talking about? http://jsfiddle.net/PWupp/

Answer (score 0):

`font` is no longer valid HTML. You should consider using semantic HTML.

Comment: Thanks Daniel but my question isn't about using it but rather is there a way to reset it. I'm faced with a situation where I can't change the html.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove Deprecated font tag and write span tag & make it's style in Css File By calss name and call it in html like:

```
<span class="font">Some large font text</span>
```

in css

```
.font{font-size:13px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML code can't be altered you can change/reset the size (and other properties) by adding these rules to the bootstrap.min.css file:

```
font[size="3"] {font-size: 10pt;}
font[size="5"] {font-size: 20pt;}
```